# No previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'FrameworkNameVersionString'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-frameworks

I created an iOS framework say CustomFramework and in the CustomFramework.h file created by Xcode has the following contents by default

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for CustomFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double CustomFrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for CustomFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char CustomFrameworkVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework  using statements like #import <CustomFramework/PublicHeader.h>
```

When I build the project, I get these warnings

```
No previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'CustomFrameworkVersionNumber'
No previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'CustomFrameworkVersionString'
```

Any idea why the default framework creation would give these warnings ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 15):

In C family languages this is caused by a variable not explicitly being defined as `static` or being declared in a header file as `extern`.

You have three options for dealing with it.

1. Place the `static` keyword in front of the definition.

   ```cpp
   static FOUNDATION_EXPORT double CustomFrameworkVersionNumber;

   static FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char CustomFrameworkVersionString[];
   ```
2. Create a separate header file with an `extern` definition for each variable.
3. Suppress the warning with `-Wmissing-variable-declarations`

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643930/how-to-change-compilation-flags-for-myframework-vers-c-in-xcode).