# How to change compilation flags for MyFramework_vers.c in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker, clang

With Apple Generic Versioning enabled, Xcode autogenerates a `MyFramework_vers.c` file in the `DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR`, which contains the version string and number defined as `const unsigned char[]` and `const double`.

However, with `-Wmissing-variable-declarations` enabled (part of `-Weverything`), this produces the warnings

> no previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'MyFrameworkVersionString'
>   no previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'MyFrameworkVersionNumber'

It seems the possible solutions are:

- add `-Wno-missing-variable-declarations` to the cflags for this file
- add `extern` declarations above the variable definitions
- add a `#import` that pulls in the `extern` declarations from the umbrella header

But I can't figure out how to do any of these since the file lives in DerivedSources and isn't a member of the Compile Sources phase. What am I missing?

(I found the `VERSION_INFO_EXPORT_DECL` setting which would allow me to mark the variables `extern`, but then I get the "extern variable has an initializer" warning, from `-Wextern-initializer`, so that doesn't help.)

Comment: Since 2015, this has been fixed in Xcode, now the generated `MyFramework_vers.c` file has 4 lines, including `extern const unsigned char MyFrameworkVersionString[];` and same for `MyFrameworkVersionNumber`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a way to modify the compiler arguments for this file, but it's possible to address the warning by abusing `VERSION_INFO_EXPORT_DECL`. Set the value to a literal newline followed by `#import "HeaderWithExternDeclarations.h"` and another literal newline. In the pbxproj it should look something like this:

```
VERSION_INFO_EXPORT_DECL = "\n#import \"MyFramework.h\"\n";
```

If you want to import a header containing Objective-C you'll also need to change `VERSION_INFO_FILE` to a value with a .m extension such as MyFramework_vers.m so the generated file is compiled as Objective-C source.

Alternatively, you can use the same hack to insert a pragma to disable the warning:

```
VERSION_INFO_EXPORT_DECL = "\n#pragma clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wmissing-variable-declarations\"\n";
```

Comment: I thought of this but initially passed it off as infeasible since the same export declaration applies to both variables. Perhaps it'll work, though it's certainly not intuitive for anyone adding a new framework target...

Comment: I tried it before posting so I can say it works as of Xcode 6.1. The value of `VERSION_INFO_EXPORT_DECL` will indeed be inserted twice, but since the `#import` directive ensures that a header is only imported once this has the desired result. A cleaner solution would certainly be preferable, but I think a change to Xcode is needed for that.

Comment: Any ideas how to set this up in an xcconfig? It seems escaped newlines aren't allowed.

Comment: That one I'm afraid I don't know.